# Executing the bash commands as a root user using jsch - java

Tags: java, android, selenium, jsch, jcabi

I have a scenario where some commands need to be executed as a root user(after executing $ sudo su not sudo $ cmd). The same I could not able to manipulate on jsch. Can someone please provide a way to execute some command after login as root. Or any equivalent library is also fine.

> Given the code sample I am trying and operation is

tail -0f /var/log/xx/xx/original.log > /var/log/xx/xx/copy.txt

```
public static String runCommandAsrootUser(String user, String password, String host, String command) {
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session;
    try {
        session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected to " + host);
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");

        channel.setInputStream(null);
        OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setPty(true);

        ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("sudo su -c "+ command);

        channel.connect();

        out.write((password + "\n").getBytes());
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("Completed");

        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
        int count = 0;
       while(true) {
           count++;
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if (i < 0) break;
                System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
            }
            if (channel.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("Exit status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }
        }
       System.out.println("Count: "+count);
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
        System.out.println("DONE");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "";
}
```

The output says /var/log/xx/xx/copy.txt: Permission denied

Second code sample

```
public static void runCommands(String username, String password, String ip, String command){
try {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession(username, ip, 22);
    session.setPassword(password);
    setUpHostKey(session);
    session.connect();

    Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");//only shell  
    channel.setOutputStream(System.out); 
    PrintStream shellStream = new PrintStream(channel.getOutputStream());  // printStream for convenience 
    channel.connect(); 
    shellStream.println("sudo su");  // Successfully executed
    shellStream.flush();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    shellStream.println("ciscotxbu"); // Successfully executed
    shellStream.flush();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    shellStream.println(command);  // ---> Not executed on the root shell.
    shellStream.flush();

    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
} catch (Exception e) { 
    System.err.println("ERROR: Connecting via shell to "+ ip);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant code from your program, even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Even it's not too complicated, by running shell commands by yourself in Android, in most cases, we are using one lib for it, [Libsu](https://github.com/topjohnwu/libsu) is working fine for us. You should consider using it, and it has no problems with calling under root.

At other hand, I would suggest to try to same implementation (because it's quite simple) with Rx action, in another library [RxShell](https://github.com/d4rken/RxShell).